# Copy Tkinter Canvas Items

Tags: python, tkinter

I need top be able to create a copy of a tkinter canvas item, so that a copy of an image can be dragged off of an original. I have dragging working for the images, but I cannot seem to copy the image item. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry for not including my code at first. I was able to solve the problem thanks to the answer that was given. Here's a trimmed down example of my code that now works:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def OnBaseButtonPress(event):
    #record the item and its location
    drag_data["item"] = c.find_closest(event.x, event.y)

    i = c.itemcget(drag_data["item"], "image") #finds the image source of the object
    refs.append(i) #keep a reference!
    c.create_image(c.coords(drag_data["item"]), image=i, tags="base") #creates an identical object at the position

    drag_data["x"] = event.x
    drag_data["y"] = event.y

def OnBaseButtonRelease(event):
    #reset drag info
    drag_data["item"] = None
    drag_data["x"] = 0
    drag_data["y"] = 0

def OnBaseMotion(event):
    #calculate how far the item has moved
    delta_x = event.x - drag_data["x"]
    delta_y = event.y - drag_data["y"]
    #move the object that amount
    c.move(drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
    #record the new position
    drag_data["x"] = event.x
    drag_data["y"] = event.y

#set up canvas and image
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
c.pack()
test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("test.png"))
c.create_image(400, 300, image=test, tags="base")
refs=[] #used to keep references to images used in functions

#bind mouse keys 
c.tag_bind("base", "<ButtonPress-1>", OnBaseButtonPress)
c.tag_bind("base", "<ButtonRelease-1>", OnBaseButtonRelease)
c.tag_bind("base", "<B1-Motion>", OnBaseMotion)

drag_data={"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}

mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi faf. This question is a bit short and vague. Please provide as much information as possible. If you're asking for code, be sure to include code that you have already tried and why it's not working the way you want it to. Please also read [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get item type [`canvas.type(item)`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.type-method), item configuration [`canvas.itemconfig(item)`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method), and etc.

And then you can recreate an identical object.

See also: [Tkinter - making a second canvas display the contents of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214054/tkinter-making-a-second-canvas-display-the-contents-of-another).