# Tkinter - Find closest object of a certain type

Tags: python, tkinter, tags, bind, tkinter-canvas

The proglem I have here is that I am not able to find the closest object of a certain type. It is best if I give you the code and for you to see what I mean:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
f=Frame(root)
f.grid()
w=Canvas(f)
def identify(event): ## this should identify the tag near to click
    item = w.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
    print item
line1=w.create_line(50,50,150,150, width=5, tags="line")
line2=w.create_line(100,100,100,350, width=3, tags="line")
line3=w.create_line(150,150,150,450, width=3, tags = "line")
w.grid(row=0, column=0)
w.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", identify)

u=Frame(f)
u.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see here, you are able to click anywhere on the screen and it will return the closest object. This is what I would like to achieve but having other objects on the screen which I **WISH TO BE IGNORED**. I am able to do this by using **tags** but the problem here is you need to click on the actual object for some reason. This code is being used to show my problem. My actual code is a Towers of Hanoi game, and I am aiming to find the closest pole so the disk is able to snap to it, but I cannot find the closest pole without clicking on every pole before moving a disk.

Here is the code showing my problem. Note: I have only changed "w.bind("", identify)" to "w.tag_bind("line", "", identify)"

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
f=Frame(root)
f.grid()
w=Canvas(f)
def identify(event): ## this should identify the tag near to click
    item = w.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
    print item
line1=w.create_line(50,50,150,150, width=5, tags="line")
line2=w.create_line(100,100,100,350, width=3, tags="line")
line3=w.create_line(150,150,150,450, width=3, tags = "line")
w.grid(row=0, column=0)
w.tag_bind("line", "<ButtonRelease-1>", identify)

u=Frame(f)
u.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Binding the event handler to the tag says 'only fire if I click on the tagged items', which is what you say happens.  Don't ask for what you don't want ;-).  Also 'closet pole' to what?

Comment: I presume closest to the clicked point in space. I do not see a problem with requiring user click on or near the top of the peg, so that a peg will be the closest.  It the item number is not in [1,3], ignore the click.

Comment: A general answer to your question might be two canvases placed over each other (with .place()), one with the click binding and the special items.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: if two canvases are on top of each other, you won't be able to see the one underneath. That's not a good solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry, I thought they could be made transparent.  Oh, well.

Comment: In my actual code I have included an "if" statement as you suggested, but this doesn't fix my problem. You have to understand that there are other objects on the canvas that I would like to be ignored. As I said, this is accomplish-able through the use of tags, but then you have to click ON the poles every time you would like an object to snap to it.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy The idea of a transparent canvas would be pretty much perfect, as I can't actually figure out a way for objects to behave the same when being "tag.bind"ed

Answer (score 1):

It's little late for you, but maybe it will be useful for others...

I just faced the same problem today, and resolved it using a second `Canvas` with duplicates of the desired items.
This canvas is never printed. It's a little tricky, but I couldn't find better.

```
draft = Canvas(w) # if w is deleted, the draft is deleted
draft.delete(ALL) # if you use the fake canvas for other uses

concerned = w.find_withtag("line") # what you want

for obj in concerned: # copy on draft

    # first, get the method to use
    if w.type(obj) == "line": create = draft.create_line
    # use "elif ..." to copy more types of objects
    else: continue

    # copy the element with its attributes
    config = {opt:w.itemcget(obj, opt) for opt in w.itemconfig(obj)}
    config["tags"] = str(obj) # I can retrieve the ID in "w" later with this trick
    create(*w.coords(obj), **config)

# use coordinates relative to the canvas
x = w.canvasx(event.x)
y = w.canvasy(event.y)

item = draft.find_closest(x,y) # ID in draft (as a tuple of len 1)
if item: item = int( draft.gettags(*item)[0] ) # ID in w
else: item = None # closest not found

print(item)
```

I wish I could have used `create(*w.coords(obj), **w.itemconfig(obj))`, but `itemconfig` without arguments returns a dictionary whose values cannot be reused.

About item copy: [Copy Tkinter Canvas Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20278179/7420421)

By the way, I used python 3, I don't know if it works in python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the type of the object selected in your `identify()` via `w.type(item)`. Since you may have lines that aren't poles in your game, you can add tags to identify which one(s) are.

Here's what I mean (note this is Python 3 code, but the same idea would have worked in Python 2.x):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
f = tk.Frame(root)
f.grid()
w = tk.Canvas(f)

def identify(event):
    item = w.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
    print(f'type of item closest to click: {w.type(item)}')
    # Check tags to see if it's a pole.
    if w.type(item) == 'line':  # Canvas line?
        for tag in w.gettags(item):  # Check its tags.
            if tag.startswith('pole'):
                print(f'  You clicked near pole {w.gettags(item)[1]}')
                break
        else:
            print('  You did not click near a pole')


line1 = w.create_line(50,50,150,150, width=5)
line2 = w.create_line(100,100,100,350, width=3, tags='pole 1')
line3 = w.create_line(150,150,150,450, width=3, tags='pole 2')
w.grid(row=0, column=0)
w.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', identify)

u = tk.Frame(f)
u.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```