# How to display and move multiple images as same image in same time python Tkinter?

Tags: python, image, oop, tkinter

I trying to improve offline GPS system. I wrote a python code for handle images such as move as follow. I want modify this code to handle multiple images.This code able to load a single image and it can move within canvas by mouse movement. I need load multiple images to this program simultaneously and show each image parts as a single image such as google maps.

```
 from Tkinter import *
 root = Tk(); root.geometry( "600x400" )
 c = Canvas( root, width = 600, height = 400, bg = "white" ); c.pack()

class MainFrame:
    """Class to move an image on a Canvas screen ( Python 2.5 )"""
   def __init__( self, image ):
     self.__image = image
     self.__x, self.__y = 250,250
     self.__picture = c.create_image( self.__x, self.__y, image =  self.__image )
     self.__move = False
     c.bind( "<Button-1>", self.startMovement )
     c.bind( "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stopMovement )
     c.bind( "<Motion>", self.movement )
     c.create_polygon((0, 100, 50, 0, 100, 100), fill="#4eccde")

 def startMovement( self, event ):
    global initi_x
    global initi_y
    initi_x = event.x
    initi_y = event.y
    self.__move = True


def stopMovement( self, event ):
    self.__move = False


def movement( self, event ):
    if self.__move:
        global initi_x
        global initi_y

        c.delete( self.__picture )
        x_axis = initi_x - event.x
        y_axis = initi_y - event.y
        self.__x -= x_axis
        self.__y -= y_axis
        print("x is ",event.x)
        print("y is ",event.y)
        #self.__x, self.__y =   event.x ,event.y

        self.__picture = c.create_image( self.__x, self.__y, image = self.__image )
        initi_x = event.x
        initi_y = event.y

        c[ "cursor" ] = "hand2"

if __name__ == "__main__":      
    im = PhotoImage( file = "new1.gif" )
    m = MainFrame( im )
    mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you kindly fix the indenting and spacing of your codes?

Answer (score 0):

I like to recommend you use the `[.move(tagOrId, xAmount, yAmount)]` method to move objects in tk.canvas. Read more from this [webpage](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html).

**Advantages of .move() method:**

1. This can help you reduce the amount of codes you need to write.
2. It is more efficient than your approach. Your present approach of creating and destroying is inefficient and I would not recommend it.
3. It will allow you to move any objects (i.e. many images) your mouse pointer touches.

**General Steps to move a tk.Canvas object :**

1. Convert mouse pointer screen coordinate to canvas coordinate.
2. Get canvas object ID using the mouse pointer canvas coordinate.
3. Initialize mouse pointer canvas coordinate as start point.
4. During move, get mouse pointer new canvas coordinate.
5. Find the delta of new and old canvas coordinate.
6. Update mouse pointer initial canvas coordinate with mouse pointer new canvas given in step 4.
7. Use that info and object ID to move the object.

**Revised Code:**
I have revised your code. See below. I have also provided comments to help you understand the general step. I have also shown in the code how you can add another image object. I trust you will be able to use these information to move on to create a tk.canvas with multiple images and moving them with your mouse pointer.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk(); root.geometry( "600x400" )
c = Canvas( root, width = 800, height = 400, bg = "white" ); c.pack()

class MainFrame:
    """Class to move an image on a Canvas screen ( Python 2.5 )"""
    def __init__( self, image0, image1 ):
        self.__image0 = image0
        self.__image1 = image1
        self.__x, self.__y = 250,250
        self.__picture0 = c.create_image( self.__x, self.__y,
                                          image =  self.__image0 )
        self.__picture1 = c.create_image( self.__x, self.__y,
                                          image =  self.__image1 )
        c.create_polygon((0, 100, 50, 0, 100, 100), fill="#4eccde")
        self.__move = False
        c.bind( "<Button-1>", self.startMovement )
        c.bind( "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stopMovement )
        c.bind( "<Motion>", self.movement )

    def startMovement( self, event ):
        self.__move = True
        self.initi_x = c.canvasx(event.x) #Translate mouse x screen coordinate to canvas coordinate
        self.initi_y = c.canvasy(event.y) #Translate mouse y screen coordinate to canvas coordinate
        print('startMovement init', self.initi_x, self.initi_y)
        self.movingimage = c.find_closest(self.initi_x, self.initi_y, halo=5) # get canvas object ID of where mouse pointer is 
        print(self.movingimage)
        print(c.find_all()) # get all canvas objects ID 

    def stopMovement( self, event ):
        self.__move = False

    def movement( self, event ):
        if self.__move:
            end_x = c.canvasx(event.x) #Translate mouse x screen coordinate to canvas coordinate
            end_y = c.canvasy(event.y) #Translate mouse y screen coordinate to canvas coordinate
            print('movement end', end_x, end_y)
            deltax = end_x - self.initi_x #Find the difference
            deltay = end_y - self.initi_y
            print('movement delta', deltax, deltay)
            self.initi_x = end_x #Update previous current with new location
            self.initi_y = end_y
            print('movement init', self.initi_x, self.initi_y)
            c.move(self.movingimage, deltax, deltay) # move object

if __name__ == "__main__":      
    im0 = PhotoImage( file = "monkey.gif" )
    im1 = PhotoImage( file = "smooch.gif" )
    im2 = PhotoImage( file = "giphy.gif" )
    m = MainFrame( im0, im1 )
    mainloop()
```

Comment: Your revised code is perfect.it works fine. But i want to move every loaded images as one image at the same time.Please Can you revise this code ?

Comment: @ireshanpathirana You can give all the rectangles a same tagname using the canvas method `.addtag_withtag(newTag, tagOrId).` right after the   `.find_closest() method`. You should also create a `Checkbutton` or a `Radiobutton`  with binding to the mouse click, release and move events, to move  all rectangles objects together.  Their codes will look  similar to above but used to move all rectangles. Revise the above code yourself and update your question with new issues if you need. See Sect . 8 to 8.6 in http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html

Comment: Thnk you so much @sun Bear. I seemed the better way is that this code revise my self. Thank you again

Comment: I want to just move all objects that contain in the canvas together every time. then should i add checkbutton or radio b. ?

Comment: @ireshanpathirana See sect 8.6. You can replace  `.find_closest()` with `.find_all()` method. Button widget was suggested just for switching binding of one task to another. For example, one button to create while another button to do movements. Normal Button can also be used. Else, assign creation to `<Button-1>` and movement to `<Button-2>`. Really depends on what u want to create. Please click the up-arrow next to my answer to indicate it is helpful if you agree. Also, pls click tick if I have  answered your question. Suggest you change your title word from "Display" to  "Display & Move". :)

Comment: Before I replaced **.find_closest()** with **.find_all()** method.but I seem it's not working.

Comment: I replaced all tag names into 7 by  'c.addtag_all(7)' and it placed '__init__' method then i add 7 to 'c.move(7,deltax,deltay) '. I seemed tag names changed successfully by .gettags(tagOrId). but images not move.

Comment: See this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7235679/5722359) on`.find_all()`. Learn to learn from online examples. Spend more time experimenting and I trust you can get it. Read the errors and follow the trail. When you finally give up, then  explain what you don't understand and the failures messages by appending them to your question above. Saying things won't work won't help you or me. :)