# How to copy contents of turtle frame embedded in tkinter canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics, deep-copy

I am trying to save the current state of a tkinter canvas to display later on. Here is the method I have tried using `deepcopy`:

```
from tkinter import *
from copy import deepcopy
root=Tk()
cv=Canvas(root)
cv.pack()
cvcopy=deepcopy(cv)
mainloop()
```

However the line `cvcopy=deepcopy(cv)` creates the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Fred/Desktop/painting/mcve.py", line 6, in <module>
    cvcopy=deepcopy(cv)
  File "C:\python files\lib\copy.py", line 173, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\python files\lib\copy.py", line 295, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\python files\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\python files\lib\copy.py", line 235, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\python files\lib\copy.py", line 173, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\python files\lib\copy.py", line 295, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\python files\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\python files\lib\copy.py", line 235, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\python files\lib\copy.py", line 173, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\python files\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    y = callable(*args)
  File "C:\python files\lib\copyreg.py", line 88, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: object.__new__(tkapp) is not safe, use tkapp.__new__()
```

Because apparently you can't just create a new widget like that. Here is the code I use to embed and draw on a `turtle` screen:

```
cv = tkinter.Canvas(self.root,width=300,height=300)
cv.pack()
t = turtle.RawTurtle(cv)
s = t.getscreen()
def toggledown():
    if t.isdown():
        t.penup()
    else:
        t.pendown()
t.speed(0)
t.ondrag(t.goto)
s.onclick(t.goto)
s.onkey(toggledown, 'space')
s.listen()
```

Does anyone know how to copy the screen, and add it again somewhere else?

Comment: You are overwriting the copy. The method can be called with `CanvasCopy = copy.deepcopy()`

Comment: @What No, that was just my unthinking mcve. I have changed it and still have the same problem.

Comment: You can't save and restore tkinter widgets by simply copying them like that.

Comment: @BryanOakley So how can I?

Comment: @BryanOakley Note that in my real code I have a user drawing on the canvas through embedded turtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to copy a widget, however if you create an identical widget at the same time, but without calling a geometry manager, you can then add it to the screen later:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
cv = Canvas(self.root, width=300, height=300)
cv.pack()
copy = Canvas(otherframe, width=300, height=300)
t = turtle.RawTurtle(cv)
s = t.getscreen()
ct = turtle.RawTurtle(copy)
cs = ct.getscreen()

def toggledown():
    if t.isdown():
            t.penup()
            ct.penup()  #no point testing twice since they're the same
        else:
            t.pendown()
            ct.pendown()

def goto(x, y):
    t.goto(x, y)
    ct.goto(x, y)

Button(self.root, text='Copy', command=copy.pack).pack()
t.speed(0)
ct.speed(0)
t.ondrag(goto)  #the copy will go to the same place
s.onclick(goto)
s.onkey(toggledown, 'space')
s.listen()
mainloop()
```

In this case, you could also save time by creating a class for the canvases:

```
class Drawing(object):

    def __init__(self, master, otherframe):
        self.cv = Canvas(master, width=300, height=300)
        self.cv.pack()
        self.copy = Canvas(otherframe, width=300, height=300)
        self.t.RawTurtle(self)
        self.s = self.t.getscreen()
        self.ct.RawTurtle(self)
        self.cs = self.ct.getscreen()
        self.ct.speed(0)
        self.t.speed(0)
        self.t.ondrag(self.goto) #the copy will go to the same place
        self.s.onclick(self.goto)
        self.s.onkey(self.toggledown, 'space')
        self.s.listen()

    def toggledown(self):
        if self.t.isdown():
            self.t.penup()
            self.ct.penup()
        else:
            self.t.pendown()
            self.ct.pendown()

    def goto(self, x, y):
        self.t.goto(x, y)
        self.ct.goto(x, y)

    def addCopy(self):
        self.copy.pack()
```

Comment: Seems like you could create a `Canvas` subclass (or perhaps via some other mechanism) that did the duplicating automatically, so that it wouldn't have to manually for every `Canvas` sub-widget.

Comment: @martineau Actually, I have, but I have (using that method) carried on with my program and now the subclass has lots of other code in and I couldn't be bothered to get only the relevant code out.

Comment: @martineau have added a code for an object. No inheritance because I'm creating two canvases and it seems simpler not to have one as the object and one as an attribute of it.

Comment: For the trivial case you have, where you apparently also have control of the drawing being done by the turtle, not subclassing and just duplicating the commands to another `Canvas` looks adequate. However subclassing `Canvas` to duplicate all its `create_xxx()` methods—there's only 9—has the advantage that it doesn't care which `turtle` methods are being used to draw things on it. You could then use an instance of this custom `Canvas` subclass to create the instance of `turtle.TurtleScreen` that the turtle uses to get copies made of _whatever_ the turtle commands produce.

Comment: That is true, but I think I'll stick with what I've got

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that seems like it could accomplish what you want. It's not a full-blown example, but rather just a demonstration of one approach to accomplishing your goal of making a copy.

Your question doesn't have any code that actually draws something on a `Canvas`, so I borrowed some from a [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/drawing/) on using `tkinter` that I found in order to have a `Canvas` with a few widgets on it for illustration purposes. It produces a window that looks like this that has a single `Button` and a single `Canvas` widget containing only three different colored rectangle widgets:

[image: screenshot of program running]

Here's the demo code showing how to iterate through all the widgets currently on the `Canvas`:

```
from pprint import pprint, pformat
from tkinter import Button, Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Colours")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        button = Button(self, text="Copy", command=self.copy_canvas)
        button.pack()

        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(30, 10, 120, 80,
                                     outline="#fb0", fill="#fb0")
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(150, 10, 240, 80,
                                     outline="#f50", fill="#f50")
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(270, 10, 370, 80,
                                     outline="#05f", fill="#05f")
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def copy_canvas(self):
        # Iterate through all the items in self.canvas and print each
        # one's type and options (which could be used to recreate it).
        for id in self.canvas.find_all():
            item_type = self.canvas.type(id)
            options = self.canvas.itemconfigure(id)
            formatted_options = pformat(options, indent=4)
            print('id: {}, type: {!r}\n{}'.format(
                    id, item_type, formatted_options))


def main():
    root = Tk()
    ex = Example()
    root.geometry("400x100+300+300")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and here's what it prints when the <kbd>Copy</kbd> button is pressed:

```
id: 1, type: 'rectangle'
{   'activedash': ('activedash', '', '', '', ''),
    'activefill': ('activefill', '', '', '', ''),
    'activeoutline': ('activeoutline', '', '', '', ''),
    'activeoutlinestipple': ('activeoutlinestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'activestipple': ('activestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'activewidth': ('activewidth', '', '', '0.0', '0.0'),
    'dash': ('dash', '', '', '', ''),
    'dashoffset': ('dashoffset', '', '', '0', '0'),
    'disableddash': ('disableddash', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledfill': ('disabledfill', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledoutline': ('disabledoutline', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledoutlinestipple': ('disabledoutlinestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledstipple': ('disabledstipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledwidth': ('disabledwidth', '', '', '0.0', '0'),
    'fill': ('fill', '', '', '', '#fb0'),
    'offset': ('offset', '', '', '0,0', '0,0'),
    'outline': ('outline', '', '', 'black', '#fb0'),
    'outlineoffset': ('outlineoffset', '', '', '0,0', '0,0'),
    'outlinestipple': ('outlinestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'state': ('state', '', '', '', ''),
    'stipple': ('stipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'tags': ('tags', '', '', '', ''),
    'width': ('width', '', '', '1.0', '1.0')}
id: 2, type: 'rectangle'
{   'activedash': ('activedash', '', '', '', ''),
    'activefill': ('activefill', '', '', '', ''),
    'activeoutline': ('activeoutline', '', '', '', ''),
    'activeoutlinestipple': ('activeoutlinestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'activestipple': ('activestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'activewidth': ('activewidth', '', '', '0.0', '0.0'),
    'dash': ('dash', '', '', '', ''),
    'dashoffset': ('dashoffset', '', '', '0', '0'),
    'disableddash': ('disableddash', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledfill': ('disabledfill', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledoutline': ('disabledoutline', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledoutlinestipple': ('disabledoutlinestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledstipple': ('disabledstipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledwidth': ('disabledwidth', '', '', '0.0', '0'),
    'fill': ('fill', '', '', '', '#f50'),
    'offset': ('offset', '', '', '0,0', '0,0'),
    'outline': ('outline', '', '', 'black', '#f50'),
    'outlineoffset': ('outlineoffset', '', '', '0,0', '0,0'),
    'outlinestipple': ('outlinestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'state': ('state', '', '', '', ''),
    'stipple': ('stipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'tags': ('tags', '', '', '', ''),
    'width': ('width', '', '', '1.0', '1.0')}
id: 3, type: 'rectangle'
{   'activedash': ('activedash', '', '', '', ''),
    'activefill': ('activefill', '', '', '', ''),
    'activeoutline': ('activeoutline', '', '', '', ''),
    'activeoutlinestipple': ('activeoutlinestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'activestipple': ('activestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'activewidth': ('activewidth', '', '', '0.0', '0.0'),
    'dash': ('dash', '', '', '', ''),
    'dashoffset': ('dashoffset', '', '', '0', '0'),
    'disableddash': ('disableddash', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledfill': ('disabledfill', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledoutline': ('disabledoutline', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledoutlinestipple': ('disabledoutlinestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledstipple': ('disabledstipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'disabledwidth': ('disabledwidth', '', '', '0.0', '0'),
    'fill': ('fill', '', '', '', '#05f'),
    'offset': ('offset', '', '', '0,0', '0,0'),
    'outline': ('outline', '', '', 'black', '#05f'),
    'outlineoffset': ('outlineoffset', '', '', '0,0', '0,0'),
    'outlinestipple': ('outlinestipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'state': ('state', '', '', '', ''),
    'stipple': ('stipple', '', '', '', ''),
    'tags': ('tags', '', '', '', ''),
    'width': ('width', '', '', '1.0', '1.0')}
```

Comment: That is interesting but I don't think would work for me in my specific case. Wondering if I should post some more code in my question.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl: Sure, go ahead, but you might want to change the title of your question a bit...

Comment: I've changed it but it feels like I'm asking a new question / multiple questions.

Comment: Artemis: Yes, your question has evolved into something at least different. It's getting late here locally, so I don't know exactly when, but I will work on it some more. Theoretically at least, the fact that the canvas was create and drawn using turtle-graphics shouldn't be too much of an issue since the `turtle` module is using `tkinter` under-the-hood (as you obviously already know)...although it might "get in the way" of doing things I suppose.

Comment: I've looked into this more. While the list of widget ids that `canvas.find_all()` method returns can be used to get an arbitrary widget's configuration options, there's no type information provided, so you don't know the kind of widget to which the options apply—and therefore can't recreate it. There are ways of overcoming that, one of which is by subclassing a `Canvas` widget and make it preserve/copy the info. That's what @Bryan Oakley does in this [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7235679/355230). You're doing it differently in your own answer. `turtle` _does_ complicate things.

Comment: Update: Although `canvas.find_all()` doesn't specify the object's type, that's fairly easy to get by using `canvas.type()`—so recreating (not copying, see @Bryan Oakley's answer) the objects appears feasible.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want. Widgets aren't pure python objects. Most of their state is in an embedded tcl interpreter.  You simply cannot make copies of tkinter widgets like this.

In short, there is no way to make a copy of a tkinter widget. The best you can do is to use the `configure` method to get all of the configuration options for the widget, and then create a new widget with the same options. Even with that, it won't store the internal state such as drawings on the canvas, text inside a text widget, etc.

Comment: So there is no way to save what the user has drawn?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl: What part of "there is no way to make a copy of a tkinter widget" was unclear?

Comment: @martineau I asked he there was no way of saving what the user had drawn, not if there was on way of copying the widget. In any case I have found a solution which I will post soon.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl: Sorry for missing the subtle difference. Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7235679/355230) answer?

Comment: @martineau Yep, before I posted this. However I was still hopeful that there would be a way to copy the canvas. You will see that I have posted an answer that works for me (actually the one I am using is more complex but easier in the long term) and is quite similar to that one in terms of how it works.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl: you can save what was drawn, but you have to do the work yourself. If all you want is to save and restore what is drawn, you can use the methods of the canvas to get a list of all objects, and from each object you can get all of the options for that object. Just wrap that up into a loop, then write it to a file.

Comment: @BryanOakley As you can see elsewhere in this post, I am using embedded turtle. Unless you know a way to get the contents of the turtle screen, this method won't work.